# capybara and RSpec: ajax response not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, rspec, devise

I'm working on writing Test cases using (`RSpec` and `Capybara`).

```
capybara (2.7.1) and 
rspec (3.4.0)
rspec-core (3.4.4)
rspec-expectations (3.4.0)
rspec-mocks (3.4.1)
rspec-rails (3.4.2)
rspec-support (3.4.1)
```

There are many answers are available but no luck!!!. These are the result which I found: [1](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/automatically-wait-for-ajax-with-capybara), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27967849/rspec-capybara-test-with-ajax-call-not-updating-record), and [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18544142/capybara-test-failing-with-ajax-response)

**capybara.rb**

```
Capybara.asset_host = 'http://localhost:3000'
Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 5
```

**session_helpers.rb**

```
module Features
  module SessionHelpers
    def sign_up_with(email, password, confirmation)
      visit new_user_registration_path
      fill_in 'Email', with: email
      fill_in 'Password', with: password
      fill_in 'Password confirmation', :with => confirmation
      click_button 'Sign up'
    end

    def signin(email, password)
      visit root_url
      find(:xpath, "//a[@class='login_box_btn']").click
      fill_in 'login_user_email',    with: email
      fill_in 'login_user_password', with: password
      click_button "LOGIN"
    end
  end
end
```

**features/users/sign_in_spec.rb**

```
feature 'Sign-In and Sign-Out', :devise do  scenario 'user cannot sign in if not registered' do
    signin('test@example.com', 'please123')
    expect(page.find(:xpath, "//div[@id='login_message']")).to  have_content("Email not found. Please provide a valid email.")
end
```

On expecting

```
find(:xpath, "//div[@id='login_message']") => ""
```

But it should not be empty.

As I'm following [RailsApps/rails-devise](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-devise) to get the things done all configuration are according to this repo.

Please do comment in case if someone need more info on this.

Answer (score 1):

try add `js: true` to scenario, like:

```
 scenario 'user cannot sign in if not registered', js: true do
```